# program to generate URL web calls with parameters in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: string, excel, variables, url, concatenation

From within an Excel spreadsheet, I'd like to call a URL website multiple times with a parameter from all the cells within a particular column from the spreadsheet.  If that column has 20 cells (eg:  B1 to B20 has numeric values), then I'd want 20 calls in the format:

https://www.zzzzzz.com/page.html?value1=$F$1&value2=[value-from-cell-B1]&value3=$G$1
https://www.zzzzzz.com/page.html?value1=$F$1&value2=[value-from-cell-B2]&value3=$G$1

There will be several fixed parameters that will be set using values from particular cells (eg: F1 and G1) but only one of them will be filled in with values from the cells of that column (i.e. value1 will be taken from a cell in the spreadsheet and used for each call, value2 will be the value from the column (eg: B1, B2, B3...B20) on each of the 20 URL calls.

A very simple way without a program is to use excel concatenation to create the URL string and then copying it 19 times (by dragging the corner of the cell) and having the value2 variable be the B1...B20 sequence.  Then I could use the hyperlink excel forumla to create a hyperlink for each of the 20 rows. Then I could click on each hyperlink to have it open up in a separate Google Chrome tab.

Sorry, I know this is probably confusing, but I hope you get the gist of what I am trying to do.
Thanks very much.  Sam.

Comment: Which is the question? Why you do not want to use the "very simple way", you have described here?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something I did to create lots of FogBugz entries using their API. I just left it at having the hyperlinks that I could click on in turn. But, if you want to open each link programmatically without human intervention then open a new Excel spreadsheet, put some URL's in column A, (www.stackoverflow.com, www.msdn.com, www.bbc.co.uk as 3 examples), paste the following code into a macro, and run it.

If you don't mind IE being closed after each call you can uncomment the line the calls objIE.quit, and if you aren't bothered about seeing IE then you can comment out or remove the line the makes objIE.Visible = true.

Enjoy.

```
Option Explicit

Sub openWebPage()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer

    row = 1 'start at row 1
    column = 1 ' go down column A

    While Sheet1.Cells(row, column) <> ""
        URL = Sheet1.Cells(row, column)
        MsgBox (URL)

        Call NavigateToURL(URL)

        row = row + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Public Sub NavigateToURL(ByVal argURL As String)
'This function found at
'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/548585-visual-basic-applications-code-open-url.html
'Modified not to close IE afterwards, and also make IE visible

  Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

  Dim objIE As Object

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  With objIE
    .Visible = False
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate argURL
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With

    objIE.Visible = True
  'objIE.Quit
  Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```